# Can't pass DateTime with timezone to marshmallow

Tags: python, datetime, flask, marshmallow, webargs

I need to pass a DateTime with timezone to a Flask api, using marshmallow/webargs arguments definitions. I have my argument defined as:

```
from webargs import fields
'from': fields.DateTime(required=False, missing=None)
```

I am calling my api passing the argument as:

```
from=2018-03-03T00:00:00.000000+00:50
```

but I obtain this error:

```
'from': ['Not a valid datetime.']
```

where I'm wrong?

Comment: Dumb question, is the date in your JSON wrapped with quotes? I tried to replicate your issue and it works perfectly: ```import webargs; f = webargs.fields.DateTime(); f.deserialize("2018-03-03T00:00:00.000000+00:50")```

Comment: There is a bug somewhere, now I am not able to give the details, but with from=2018-03-03T00:00:00.000000-00:50 it works. The "+" lets the deserialisation not working.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. The "+" is coming in as " " (a space) after decoding the url, because the query string has not been url encoded. To get around this, you can url encode your query string to get:

`from=2018-03-03T00%3A00%3A00.000000%2B00%3A50`

or directly use "%2B" instead of "+" to get:

`from=2018-03-03T00:00:00.000000%2B00:50`